# regex, http link which is not url to image

Tags: regex, scala

I'm parsing text in Sscala and using regex:

```
val imageLink = "(http?:\\/\\/.*\\.(?:png|jpg|gif|bmp|jpeg))".r.findAllIn(postText).toList
val htmlLink = "http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?"
            .r.findAllIn(postText).toList.filterNot(s => s.contains("jpg") || s.contains("jpeg")
              || s.contains("png") || s.contains("gif") || s.contains("bmp"))
```

But I dont want to use all those s.contains. I would like in regex find http links which doesn't end jpg, bmp and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to use negative lookahead `(?!)` expressions:

```
"(?!.*(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp))http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*)?"
```

You may also omit brackets in `http(s)?` -> `https?` because `?` will only work for `s` character in both cases.

Further improvement of the regexp would be checking for the extension at exact place where it might appear in the URL.